# Unable to save cookie with Laravel 5.4

Tags: cookies, laravel-5, setcookie

Unable to store cookie with the following code in Laravel 5.4

```
$row = cookie('name', 'value', 52400);

This one is also not working

Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('name', 'value', 'minutes'));
```

Can you please have a look into this,what can be the issue ?

Comment: Are you actually providing values to `Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('name', 'value', 'minutes'));`? Like `Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('myCookie', true, 60));`?

Answer (score 1):

Try attach the `cookie()` method to a `respomse()`:

```
return response()->view('file_name')->cookie('name', 'value', $minutes);
```

Here are some examples: 
 http://coursesweb.net/laravel/cookies

- For Cookie queuing you have to add this line in controller to use Cookie facades:

  `use Cookie;`

Then use:

```
Cookie::queue('name', 'value', $minutes);
```